# How to store Configuration file and read it using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, webpack, flux

I am new on react.js I have implemented one component in which I am fetching the data from server and use it like,

```
CallEnterprise:function(TenantId){


    fetchData('http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8090/Enterprises?TenantId='+TenantId+' &format=json').then(function(enterprises) 
    {
        EnterprisePerspectiveActions.getEnterprise(enterprises);
    }).catch(function()
    {
        alert("There was some issue in API Call please contact Admin");
        //ComponentAppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
        //    actionType: MetaItemConstants.RECEIVE_ERROR,
        //    error: 'There was a problem getting the enterprises'
        //});
    });
},
```

I want to store Url in configuration file so when I deployed this on Testing server or on Production I have to just change the url on config file not in js file but I don't know how to use configuration file in react.js

Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you use webpack or some tool to compile the js code?

Comment: It would be common to send that value, set and read from an environment variable to the web page as a global value available within your JavaScript. Then, use it to fetch data.

Comment: @PetrBela : yes I am using webpack to build bundle.js but I am taking about configuration file like web.config in .net

Answer (score 145, accepted):

With webpack you can put env-specific config into the `externals` field in `webpack.config.js`

```
externals: {
  'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {
    serverUrl: "https://myserver.com"
  } : {
    serverUrl: "http://localhost:8090"
  })
}
```

If you want to store the configs in a separate JSON file, that's possible too, you can require that file and assign to `Config`:

```
externals: {
  'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./config.dev.json'))
}
```

Then in your modules, you can use the config:

```
var Config = require('Config')
fetchData(Config.serverUrl + '/Enterprises/...')
```

For React:

```
import Config from 'Config';
axios.get(this.app_url, {
        'headers': Config.headers
        }).then(...);
```

Not sure if it covers your use case but it's been working pretty well for us.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW we've since learned that it's better to use JSON to avoid syntax errors. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: OMG, I am happy you were "listening".  I went straight to a JSON import initially and it didn't work.  Luckily your update let me on to the importance of executing JSON.stringify against my imported JSON.

Comment: @PetrBela What should be the format of config.json. How does it differentiate between production and local

Comment: It doesn't. You might want to have two separate json files probably. Updated the example.

Comment: I cant get this to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065832/webpack-include-configuration-file-as-external-resource?noredirect=1#comment59778282_36065832

Comment: Hmm I haven't realized require parses the JSON file. Because `externals` expects a code to be evaluated, you need to stringify the JSON.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I get this error : [Error: Cannot find module 'Config'] when using require('Config')

Comment: guys from your webpack.config.js you need to define the path to the json file on your externals, for example require('./config.dev.json'), this is to prevent it from mistaken as node_modules. Then on your modules you can omit the path and require('config') if that is the variable you set from externals

Comment: I had to restart webpack after change

Comment: Would you please share whole webpack.config or the application in github? Thanks

Comment: What if I want webpack not bundle seperate config file into output.bundle.js? If it would be a seperate from bundle, may I still  require('Config')? Thanks

Comment: How did any of you get this to work? I do it exactly as suggested and I'm getting 'Cannot find module 'Config'', same as @amgohan.

Comment: It work for me in application but from eslint i get `Unable to resolve path to module 'Config'`

Comment: Works lika charm.

Comment: @PiotrGalas you should install the eslint-import-resolver-webpack package

Comment: Is there any way without restarting webpack, Updated Configurations can be accessed??

Comment: Did anyone manage to create working configuration webpack file? It seem for me that only converting custom setup will help:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup
I'm surprised that nobody mentioned it)

Comment: For me project created using create-react-app, `process.env.ENV` is `undefined` so i was not able to get env based values, but I am able to get value using `process.env.NODE_ENV`. Am I missing something?

Comment: One thing I'm having trouble with is that I'm already excluding the node_modules folder in the webpack.config.js file with the following: externals:[nodeExternals()] I have nodeExternals defined above as follows: var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')). Where does a custom reference to a configuration file fall into this setup?

Comment: This answer is outdated, most folks use create-react-app now to make react apps, which does not provide a webpack.config.js anymore. If you are coming here after using create-react-app, do not eject your config! Do not create your own webpack hell. Use the REACT_APP_ env vars in the other solution, which get rolled up into the static builds.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but in the browser I get the error "ReferenceError: require is not defined". Is there something else I need?

Comment: Sorry but `JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./config.dev.json'))` this line always returns the last file i.e. `config.dev.json` in both the modes

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks checking for an environment string and reacting off that as a very poor solution?

Answer (score 93):

If you used Create React App, you can set an environment variable using a .env file. The documentation is here:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Basically do something like this in the .env file at the project root.

```
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef
```

Note that the variable name must start with **REACT_APP_**

You can access it from your component with

```
process.env.REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE
```

Comment: just remember your variable name **must** start with `REACT_APP_`

Comment: I have an ASP.NET Core app created with React template, and all I did was add an empty file under 'ClientApp' folder and put `REACT_APP_MYSETTING=value` in it, then refer to it as `process.env.REACT_APP_MYSETTING` in my JSX code, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: .env does not work to me at all in create-react-app project

Comment: You will have to restart your project on npm once you've added .env to your root directory

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern. API endpoints are not secrets that should be defined in an environment variable. They're part of the definition of the app.

Comment: @Rob the point isn't that it's a secret, it's that it changes by environment. I have an application that deploys to 1200 servers in four data centers across the country, on up to 8 clusters per data center, and local API endpoints are applied on each cluster. You don't want to hard-code something like that...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dotenv package no matter what setup you use. It allows you to create a .env in your project root and specify your keys like so

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT=8000
```

In your applications entry file your just call dotenv(); before accessing the keys like so

```
process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT
```

Comment: although I think you need to specify your keys starting with `REACT_APP_`

Answer (score 1):

## In case you have a .properties file or a .ini file

Actually in case if you have any file that has key value pairs like this:

```
someKey=someValue
someOtherKey=someOtherValue
```

You can import that into webpack by a npm module called [properties-reader](https://github.com/steveukx/properties)

I found this really helpful since I'm integrating react with Java Spring framework where there is already an application.properties file. This helps me to keep all config together in one place.

1. Import that from dependencies section in package.json

`"properties-reader": "0.0.16"`

2. Import this module into webpack.config.js on top

`const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');`

3. Read the properties file

`const appProperties = PropertiesReader('Path/to/your/properties.file')._properties;`

4. Import this constant as config

`externals: {
    'Config': JSON.stringify(appProperties)
}`

5. Use it as the same way as mentioned in the accepted answer

`var Config = require('Config')
fetchData(Config.serverUrl + '/Enterprises/...')`

Comment: Your step 2 about webpack.config.js, if one is using create-react-app then there is no webpack config (or it is hidden). How to proceed in that case?

Answer (score 0):

So not exactly a configuration file but you can also add environment variables in the `package.json` start script.

Before:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ....
  },
```

After:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_TEST_ENV_VAR=TEST_DATA react-scripts start",
    ...
  },
```

You can read these now using the `process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_ENV_VAR` in your react code.

In a somewhat similar fashion you can also just move that env variable/config param to the command `npm start` command line.

So again before to launch your react app via command line:
`npm start`

After: `REACT_APP_TEST_ENV_VAR=TEST_DATA npm start`