# Webpack -- include configuration file as external resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

As the applicaiton grows, it is time to remove the hard coded things from the code. Time to implement proper configuration file.

I am thinking to use webpack, and to include configuration file, so I can require it in react.js application.

This is what I have done (webpack.config):

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
entry: [
  './src/app.js'
],
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/js'),
  filename: 'app.built.js'
},
externals: {
  'Configurator':  require('./config/config-dev.json')
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
  ]
}
 };
```

My JSON file:

```
{
 "product": {
 "getProducts": "/product",
 "updateProduct": "/updateproduct",
 "deleteProduct": "/deleteproduct"
},
 "project": {
 "getProjects": "/project",
 "updateProduct": "/updateproject",
 "deleteProduct": "/deleteproject"    
}  
}
```

And in one of the components in React components I try this:

```
var MyFile = require('Configurator');
```

There is no error, webpack finds the file. In console I see this:

```
var MyFile = __webpack_require__(412);
```

But MyFile is undefined.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you want to use [`externals`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) here. Maybe [`alias`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)?

Comment: Hmmm... I have checked the documentation from the links... would you care to provide an example with alias? :)

Comment: The config file I am trying to import is just JSON, not the js. And its not located in node_modules :)

Answer (score 7):

`require` automatically parses the JSON file. `externals` expects a string to evaluate, so you'll need to stringify the object:

```
externals: {
  'Configurator': JSON.stringify(require('./config/config-dev.json'))
},
```

Comment: 'Configurator': JSON.stringify(require('./config/config-dev.json')) does not work in one liner. If I require the file at the top of the webpack.config and then stringify it, then it works...

Comment: @wexoni i tried it and still getting the error `Cannot find module 'Config'`

Comment: @Sag1v Did you name the field Config or Configurator?

Comment: Config (sorry for not being clear) i followed another post where you mentioned for this post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30602665/3148807

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but when I try this the JSON is not parsed. See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830412/