# How to get and store endpoint information from json?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux

I have a react / redux app that have a lot of ajax calls to an endpoint.

The endpoint url is written to a config.json file;

{endpoint: 'apiEndpoint.url'}

How should I get this URL from that file and where should I store it?

I have a lot of actions that uses fetch to get the data.

the endpoint url is written to the config file during release, so I can't access it before. It has to be on "runtime".

Comment: Do you use webpack to build your app? If so, does your config.json file is being written before or after running webpack build script?

Comment: I do use webpack, but the config.json file is written after webpack build. The config.json is written in a post-deployment step.

Comment: See this, it worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065832/webpack-include-configuration-file-as-external-resource