# ES6 import from a JSON string literal via webpack externals

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

The question: Why won't `import` parse my JSON string provided as a webpack `externals` member?

I have a group of React apps that need to share a JSON configuration file, which I want webpack (v4) to inline into each app during the build. Based on answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065832/webpack-include-configuration-file-as-external-resource/36067125#36067125) and similar examples like the "Using Webpack" section in this [article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-store-and-read-configuration-files-using-react), it looks like this should work, but the JSON string imports as a string value, it is not parsed into an object.

JSON:

```json
{ "api": "https://localhost:5050/api" }
```

Webpack (modifying a config produced by another package):

```js
config.externals.push({
  'AppConfig': JSON.stringify(require(path.resolve(configPath, "app-config.json")))
});
```

Module:

```js
import Config from 'AppConfig';
```

I'm using a component to read the OpenAPI schema:

```html
<ApiService schema={Config.api}> ...
```

The error shows the JSON is not parsed, it is imported as a string literal:

```
GET https://localhost:9000/%7B%22api%22:%22https://localhost:5050/api%22%7D net::ERR_ABORTED 404
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The webpack config works, obviously. And I know the configuration itself is good, if I change the `import` to reference the JSON file directly, it works as expected. But that requires using lots of `../../../` relative path garbage I'm trying to avoid. I am also not interested in the `export default` approach in a .js file that I've seen people use for similar questions.

Am I missing a webpack or Babel plug-in somewhere, perhaps?

Comment: What if you wrote a `resolve.alias` against a module somewhere in a good place that imports the JSON file? That would avoid the problem of relative paths while giving you a single place in the codebase where to manage configuration. There are other ways too but I have a feeling this could fit your use case well.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen Someone over in the webpack repo just suggested the same thing. I had tried using `path.resolve` and `path.relative` with `exports` but for some reason that results in trying to read the file from the server at runtime as a module, which doesn't work out well. But I'll definitely give `alias` a shot at work on Monday. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use an [`alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) with a relative path. The extra `path` steps are because this is in a utility `module.exports` that modifies an existing webpack configuration object. The `npm_config_top_dir` environment variable is specific to our monorepo setup (Lerna runs these scripts and the shared config file is in that root directory).

```js
const pathToCallerSourceCode = path.resolve(process.cwd(), "./src");
const appConfigFullPathname = path.resolve(process.env.npm_config_top_dir, "app-config.json");
const appConfigRelativePathname = path.relative(pathToCallerSourceCode, appConfigFullPathname);

Object.assign(config.resolve, { alias: { AppConfig: appConfigRelativePathname }});
```