# How can I use a config file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Let's say I have 5 jsx files and each file uses some config parameter.
My index.js file imports all of these 5 jsx files.

Instead of having my config data spread accross 5 files, is there a way for my jsx files to get the data from a global JS object which has loaded the data from a config file?

I've seen some examples, but I've not been able to get them to work.
[JS6 import function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) | [Example using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568796/how-to-store-configuration-file-and-read-it-using-react)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming ES6:

```
config.js

export const myConfig = { importantData: '', apiUrl: '', ... };
```

Then:

```
jsxFileOne.js, jsxFileTwo.js, ...

import { myConfig } from 'config.js';
```

There are other ways to import & export things globally leveraging webpack, but this should get you started.

Comment: ok for static settings, but when loading config is expensive and you don't want it to execute that logic every time that file is referenced. Looking for a way to load this on startup and re-use

Comment: @SonicSoul The imports are cached, so the config object itself is not computed multiple times as long as you use import statement.

Comment: @Thava oh interesting! i will test this!

Answer (score 1):

If your project is built using Webpack, consider using [node-env-file](https://github.com/grimen/node-env-file).
Example config file snippets:

*development.env*
`API_SERVER_URL=https://www.your-server.com`

webpack.config.js

```
const envFile = require('node-env-file');
...
const appSettingsFile = isDevBuild ? '/settings/development.env' : '/settings/production.env';

try {
    envFile(path.join(__dirname + appSettingsFile));
} catch (error) { 
    console.log("Failed to read env file!: " + __dirname + appSettingsFile);
}
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
            API_SERVER_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_SERVER_URL)
        }
    })
    ...
]
```

Inside your js/jsx code, you can now access `process.env.API_SERVER_URL` variable which will contain the required value.

It seems [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package is more popular, you can try this out as well.

Comment: i had to use this before , but as your api endpoints grows , your webpack file is becomes a mess, the best solution i found so far is a `ServiceConfig.js` file that uses a singleton pattern to implement all fetch actions of your webApp...

Answer (score 1):

**One purpose to add *config.js* file is to use static data which needs to be used all over the application**.

Suppose we want our BASE URL to configure for local, test and prod environment then we can create a config file with different values based on the environment we are using so our main application code will be untouched, only the base url will be changed based on environment we are working upon.

1. we can create "*config.js*" under project root directory.

   `your_project_name > config.js`
2. You can add static data in config.js file

   `export const configData =  {`

   `BASE_URL: "https://your-domain.com/app-url/"`

   `}`
3. Now suppose you want to use the configData in "App.js" file under the src folder of project root directory

   `import { configData } from "../Config";`

   `const verify_link = configData.BASE_URL + "any_custom_link";`
4. You can import and use the 'configData' wherever required all over your application the same way.

Hope it helps!