# how to use webpack externals for config data in react/redux app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'd like to use a config file in a react/redux app. 
In this thread

[How to store Configuration file and read it using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568796/how-to-store-configuration-file-and-read-it-using-react#)

i found a nice solution but i receive the following error when using require in my redux action file.

Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'Config'

Comment: What do you have in your config file? posting a sample would help writing answers.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it with the following webpack config:

```
plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env':{
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
        }
    }),
],
externals: {
    'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {
        api: "http://www.vitto.mt.it/eventi/api/public/"
    } : {
        api: "/react/eventi/api/public/"
    })
},
```

and calling it:

```
var Config = require('Config');
```

But i still have to set manually the NODE_ENV value. How can i set it using an external file?