# Reading config files in create react app setup in craco

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, config, create-react-app, craco

I am looking to read my configuration files depends on my environment without ejecting the webpack of my create-react-app.

I found some [StackOverflow references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30602665) to change the Webpack config for reading config files depends on the environment.

```
externals: {
  'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./config.dev.json'))
}
```

I am having the following files under `src/config/globals/` directory.

```
prod.js
dev.js
test.js
```

I just tried to pick correct config files depends on the environment.
My craco config file content,

```
module.exports = {
    externals: {
      config: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./src/config/globals/prod.js') : require('./src/config/globals/dev.js'),
    },
  }
```

But when I try to import the config file inside my components, I am getting `Module not found` error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'config'
```

My import statement,

```
import GlobalConfig from 'config'
```

way of exporting the config file objects is,

```
module.exports = GlobalConfig;
```

How can I read the config file depends on the environment which setup by craco config?

Answer (score 0):

The following craco.config.js worked for me:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: (webpackConfig) => {
            webpackConfig.externals = {
                'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./conf/config.dev.json'))
            };
            return webpackConfig;
        },
    }
};
```