# Can't configure Tailwind inside React MicroFrontends App

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, micro-frontend, craco

Trying to **configure Tailwind into my MicroFrontend App**.

There are some problems with postCss, which Craco helps to solve, but for that I need to use Craco inside `npm start` script, like that:

> ```
>   "start": "craco start",
> ```

The problem is that right now I'm using webpack serve inside the strat script:

> ```
> "start": "webpack serve --config=config/webpack.dev.js",
> ```

How can I use Craco to solve my problem, but still use my webpack config file.

Tried this solution but it won't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70276756/11927087.