# How can I get my React component to read an external value?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a value in my `appSettings.json` file...something like this:

```
  "AccessControl": {
    "SystemGated": "True"
  },
```

How can I test that value inside my React component? I am imaging something like this:

```
export function accessIsGated(value) {
    if (value = "True") {
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```

But I am not sure how I can access that value in my `appSettings.json` file...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store Configuration file and read it using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568796/how-to-store-configuration-file-and-read-it-using-react)

Comment: @MarioSantini kind of?  I am not sure what web pack is though.

Comment: is this a remote file? if this is the case, Matteo Di Blasio's answer should hel. Otherwise you can probably just import it `import appSettings from '../locales/appSettings.json'` and then use it like so: `appSettings.AccessControl.SystemGated`

Comment: @Iorweth333 No it is a local file in the same drive as all of my React code. It is part of the project.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell ok, as iroweth333 suggested, you can just import the json file ten and access all of it as a JS object.

Comment: I meat what it's going to be like when the application will work in production mode. Or in another words: do you need to change it after you create a production build (i.e. it will be remote) or can it be a part of the bundle (i.e. you need to rebuild and redeploy the project to change it)?

Comment: @Iorweth333 Hi yes, the idea is to be able to change the `appSettings.json` file in production without having to change the code.

Comment: ok, in this case you need to fetch it, either by  Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or some alternative, like Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios). Importing won't do.

Comment: @Iorweth333 just curious, why would importing it not work?  thanks

Comment: Because the it becomes a part of the bundle - it will become embedded inside a .js file with all other code of your application. This implies you have to rebuild and redeploy you application to change it.Theoretically you could of course modify the .js file if you have access to, but this would be a workaround, not the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand you're trying to access an internal json file by importing it in your React component, i'll leave you an example with a simple component example:

```
import data from "../data.json"
        
        export default function Index() {
          console.log(data)
          
          return (
            <div>
              {data.AccessControl.SystemGated}
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Comment: Isn't fetch used for contacting an API?  Thank you

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell i'm sorry for the misunderstanding, try to include the file like this, as iroweth333 suggested

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell yes, fetch, among other things, can be used to call an API. But think about what "fetch" means: you are about to fetch a file with your configuration to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is **very simplified example** of a React component, which fetches a JSON file and puts it into state for further use:

```
function MyApp() {
  const [config, setConfig] = React.useState(undefined);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https:/my.app.com/appSettings.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setConfig(data));
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {config ? JSON.stringify(config) : 'Fetching...'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It displays it on the screen, but you can of course do whatever with it, including but not limited to: using it directly, passing it down to children, putting it in a `Context` to avoid prop-drilling and so on.